# Replacing Javascript string with an image

Tags: jquery, image, replace, title, mmenu

I want to replace the word "Orkid" with displaying an image. I know a bit about CSS and HTML codes but I'm not familiar with Javascript.

```
//  The menu

$('#menu')
.mmenu({
    extensions      : [ 'widescreen', 'theme-white', 'effect-slide-menu' ],         
    dividers        : {
        fixed   : true
    },
    navbar          : {
        title   : 'Orkid'
    },
    navbars         : [{
        position: 'top',
        content : ['searchfield']
    }, {
        position: 'top'
    }, {
        position: 'bottom',
        content : ['<div>lorem</div>',]
    }]
});
```

Comment: What is `.mmenu`? I assume it's some kind of jQuery plugin...

Comment: Yes, please give us a bit more context. What is mmenu?

Comment: Yes exactly. Can you help please?

Comment: I assumed it was http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/api.html but your options aren't listed there. Can you link to the documentation?

Comment: Sigh... Alright, let me reveal the secret: I'm trying to edit the jquery menu of the website "www.mmenu.frebsite.ml"

Comment: I get an error when I try to go to that URL.

Comment: When I correct `ml` to `nl`, it's the same site I referenced. But I don't see any of those options.

Comment: Never mind, I was looking on the wrong page, options are on http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/options/

Comment: Oh brother, I really apologize for mistype, actually it's ".nl"
In fact, there's a word (mmenu) below the "search bar" of this website that i want to replace this word with a displaying a picture. still can't see it?

Comment: It looks like the `title` option is only allowed to be a string, not any other type of element. If it interprets it as HTML, you could try `title: '<img src="URL">'`. If that doesn't work, you may need to write custom code to modify the DOM after you run the plugin.

Comment: Yes you are right. Seems difficult and even impossible for an amateur like me. Can you at least suggest a way, in which i remove/delete the title bar itself? If replacing it with an image isn't easy, then there should be at least a way to remove the "whole" title bar. I want nothing BUT only a blank space instead of the word displayed as "title". Thank you brother.